# how to setup tasker for bt on call

Tags: samsung, tasker, headset

could someone help me with this? 
I want the tasker to automatically turn on the bt,and switch off wifi and data when a call is made or received...
also to undo everytning after the end of the call....rreturn to previous state....

Also need to connect automatically to my headset after the bt is enabled...
I cant cope with the % % and the orders of the tasker...
please if anyone could help it would be great

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
Profile : Event > Phone Offhook 
              Enter Task: BT On, WiFi Off, Mobile Data Off 
              Exit Task: BT Off, WiFi On, Mobile Data On

As long as your headset is paired and on, it should reconnect automatically.